# WebSocket return undefined after fetching user, but console.log prints the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I've been working with a websocket to fetch users.

I open the connection and send the messages to get the data, but if I want to return that user and use it elsewhere, I get undefined, but when running console.log inside the function, it gives me the user.

Here is my code :

```
export function fetchUser(id: number) {
  const connection = generateConnection();
  connection.onopen = () => {
    connection.send(
      JSON.stringify(
        '{"msg":"connect","version":"1","support":["1","pre2","pre1"]}',
      ),
    );
    connection.send(
      JSON.stringify(
        `{"msg":"method","id":"1","method":"Users.getUser","params":[${id}]}`,
      ),
    );
  };
  connection.on('message', async (event) => {
    const data = event.toString();
    if (data[0] == 'a') {
      const a = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data.substring(1))[0]);
      if (a.msg == 'result') {
        if ('error' in a) {
          console.log(a.error.error);
          connection.close();
          return null;
        } else {
          let user= a.result;
          console.log(user) // returns the user

          return user; // return undefined
          
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
console.log(fetchUser(1));
```

Comment: You are doing this the wrong way. Your trying to use a socket connection like a regular http request. In other words you have setup a complex system to do something simple. Secondly, your return is inside an anonymous function which returns to the caller in this case 'connection.on' which could care less about the return. You could make this work with a promise and I almost posted that answer but it would be fundamentally wrong even if it fixed your problem. You have an architect problem.

Comment: Hey  @MichaelHobbs, thanks for the quick answer, how do you advise me to fetch all the users from a socket like that ? I have to do it each hour and fetch 6000 users each time, I was trying to create a function that fetch one user and after that do a loop to get all the users

Comment: Let me make sure I understand the problem. There is a socket connection that you do not control. You need to use said socket to pull data from and do something with? This code is running inside node and not the browser?

Comment: Yes Exactly, I'm using a socket that I do not control, they don't have an api for me to use, so I have to pass through the socket and yes its inside node, I have to get all the users and add them to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Given the details I have this should be at least close to something functional. I've added a number of comments where the exist code doesn't make sense.

```js
const state = {
    isReady: false,
}
const connection = generateConnection();
const sendMsg = (msg) => connection.send(JSON.stringify(msg))

connection.onopen = () => {
    sendMsg({"msg": "connect", "version": "1", "support": ["1", "pre2", "pre1"]})
    state.isReady = true; // not sure if this is true yet
};

export async function fetchUser(id: number) {
    if (!state.isReady) {
        throw new Error("Not ready yet")
    }
    sendMsg({"msg": "method", "id": "1", "method": "Users.getUser", "params": [id]})
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.once('message', async (event) => {
            // why event.toString()? what is it? Is this JSON data?
            const data = event.toString();
            // what are you doing here?
            if (data[0] === 'a') {
                // this much be wrong and has something to do with event.toString()
                const a = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data.substring(1))[0]);
                // this is likely wrong too ie should be something like a.result && a.error
                if (a.msg === 'result') {
                    if ('error' in a) {
                        console.log(a.error.error);
                        return resolve(null)
                    }
                    let user = a.result;
                    console.log(user) // returns the user
                    return resolve(user); // return undefined
                }
            }
        });
    })
}

fetchUser(1)
    .then((user) => console.log(user))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got inspired from your code and got something to work:

```
import { generateConnection } from './generate-connection';
const connection = generateConnection();
export async function fetchUser(id: number) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    console.log('Opening connection...');
    connection.onopen = () => {
      connection.send(
        JSON.stringify(
          '{"msg":"connect","version":"1","support":["1","pre2","pre1"]}',
        ),
      );
      console.log('Connection opened');
      console.log('Sending message...');
      connection.send(
        JSON.stringify(
          `{"msg":"method","id":"1","method":"Users.getUser","params":[${id}]}`,
        ),
      );
    };
    connection.on('message', async (event) => {
      // yes it gives json data;
      const data = event.toString();
      if (data[0] == 'a') {
        // when the response come it's a string with a prefix 'a'
        const a = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data.substring(1))[0]);
        if (a.msg == 'result') {
          if ('error' in a) {
            console.log(a.error.error);
            return null;
          } else {
            resolve(a.result);
            connection.close();
          }
        }
      }
    });
    connection.on('error', function (error) {
      console.log('Connection Error: ' + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function () {
      console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
    });
  });
}

fetchUser(1).then((data) => console.log(data.name));
```

The problem with one , is when I loop , I only get the first user

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const data: any = await fetchUser(i);
  console.log(data.name);
}
```

gives :

```
Opening connection
connection opened
sending message
Jack
Opening connection
connection opened
sending message
```

and it exits...